# I got a POSKeyError in my plone site, and only broken in a floder, other contents are correct

Tags: plone, zodb

In my plone site, an error message in a folder, as below

> POSKeyError('\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x10',) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: s)

And, in client1/event.log, I can find the detail message as below:

Traceback (innermost last):

> Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
>   Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
>   Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
>   Module plone.dexterity.content, line 707, in manage_delObjects
>   Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 540, in manage_delObjects
>   Module Products.BTreeFolder2.BTreeFolder2, line 477, in _delObject
>   Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
>   Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
>   Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
>   Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
>   Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
>   Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
>   Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
>   Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
>   Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
>   Module OFS.subscribers, line 101, in dispatchObjectWillBeMovedEvent
>   Module zope.container.contained, line 152, in dispatchToSublocations
>   Module OFS.subscribers, line 81, in sublocations
>   Module plone.folder.ordered, line 87, in objectValues
>   Module plone.folder.ordered, line 75, in objectIds
>   Module plone.folder.default, line 152, in idsInOrder
>   Module plone.folder.default, line 163, in _order
>   Module zope.annotation.attribute, line 44, in get
>   Module ZODB.Connection, line 860, in setstate
>   Module ZODB.Connection, line 901, in _setstate
>   Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 833, in load
>   Module ZEO.ServerStub, line 176, in loadEx
>   Module ZEO.zrpc.connection, line 768, in call
>   POSKeyError: 0x7310

I have no idea to solve it, Any suggestions?

Comment: You may read thru this guide --> http://plonechix.blogspot.ch/2009/12/definitive-guide-to-poskeyerror.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solve this problem referent this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem reference this post:

http://plonechix.blogspot.tw/2009/12/definitive-guide-to-poskeyerror.html

The complete operation like below,

Into the command line

> bin/zopepy

And then,

> from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager
>
> from Testing import makerequest
>
> from ZODB import FileStorage, DB
>
> import transaction
>
> storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('path_to/Data.fs')
>
> db = DB(storage)
>
> connection = db.open()
>
> root = connection.root()
>
> app = root['Application']
>
> admin = app.acl_users.getUserById('admin')
>
> admin = admin.**of**(app.acl_users)
>
> newSecurityManager(None, admin)
>
> req=makerequest.makerequest(app.mysite.bad_folder)
>
> req.manage_delObjects(['bad_content'])
>
> transaction.commit()

At last, must be clear and rebuild catalog at portal_catalog in ZMI.